# Taskbar apps keep reappearing on start up despite unpinning them on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, boot, taskbar, xml

Every time I boot my computer on Windows 10, Microsoft Word and Excel keep being pinned on the taskbar despite me having unpinned them before signing out.
I've tried changing the xml file located in %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\DefaultLayouts.xml using some code samples from [microsoft docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/configure-windows-10-taskbar#sample-taskbar-configuration-added-to-start-layout-xml-file). They keep reappearing however.
I'm on Windows 10.0.19042 Build 19042.

Comment: Are these apps restarting after restart? That could cause this. Look in Settings, Sign in options and turn off that feature.

Comment: @John Restart apps are turned off in the settings already.

Comment: Try the Windows 10 initial repairs. Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.  dism.exe  /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup   dism.exe /online /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  SFC /SCANNOW   Restart and test.

Comment: Before you restart, make sure both Word and Excel (all Office apps) are closed. That will help with troubleshooting.

Comment: @John Thanks for the help but I'm really confused on what you're suggesting I do here. What commands do I input?

Comment: Is it an official computer? There can be group policies on official computer to add pinned applications.

Answer (score 1):

OP here, I lost access to the account on which I posted the question.

The issue was that I had to modify another xml file: C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\LayoutModification.xml

There, I deleted the two lines in the CustomTaskBarLayout section containing Word and Excel. The apps aren't showing up anymore after restart.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue (some icons misplaced in the Task Bar), try the Windows 10 Initial (first) Repair Steps.

> (1) Open cmd.exe (start, cmd.exe) with Run as Administrator. This
> works from the Start button. Type in cmd.exe - see Command  selection
> at the top, right click, and select Run as Administrator.
>
> Now run the following 3 commands in order:
>
> (2) dism.exe  /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup
>
> (3) dism.exe  /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
>
> (4) SFC /SCANNOW
>
> When then is done, restart the computer. Just before restarting, make
> sure Word is closed, Excel is closed, and in fact all Office apps are
> closed. Restart and see if the icons are still there.

If the above does not help, run a Windows 10 Repair Install.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. If the Repair will not run as per above, use
> the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key, then run
> Setup on the USB Key.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.
>
> Start with the option to Keep Everything.
>
> You can also Keep Data, or Keep Nothing. Keep Nothing is very close to
> a clean install.

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work. Windows did find some corrupt files but the apps are still pinning themselves on startup.

Comment: The step to take next (and I amended my answer) is to run a Windows 10 Repair Install. I have done these numerous times.