# Windows 11 re-pins apps to taskbar after every restart

Tags: windows, windows-11

I have unpinned edge (and two other default apps) from my taskbar several times but after every restart they reappear.

What I've tried:

checked group policies and none are configured that cause this behaviour

a supposed workaround of navigating to %appdata%/local/microsoft/windows/shell and editing the LayoutModifcation file but there is no CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection section which I can edit and no mention of the taskbar at all

checked regedit to see if there is some local config that would cause this issue - could not find one

Comment: Can you find Edge in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`? See also if [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1624238/8672) helps.

Comment: Thank you - unfortunately edge was not in that folder, only apps I have pinned. Also this answer relates to the layoutmodification file which I have already checked

Comment: What about creating a `LayoutModification.xml` file as described in the last entry of [this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/all/prevent-ms-edge-from-pinning-to-taskbar-after/0419921c-b22a-4a90-80dc-d1810f9556ef). Search also every `LayoutModification.xml` file on the computer.

Comment: ... If everything fails, you could use this brute-force [method](https://superuser.com/a/1294350/8672).

Comment: Thanks harry. I tried adding the customtaskbarlayoutcollection as suggested in that answer. Unfortunately the next restart the apps were back and the extra lines I had put in LayoutModification.xml were gone. I tried this twice and it was the same result, This must be a windows 11 bug as I have seen multiple people have this same issue

Comment: So it seems that Microsoft really intends forcing it. This leaves only the login task method, if that's acceptable as an answer.

Comment: Is the computer part of a domain managed by a server?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Edge (I use Edge all the time).  But other apps can normally be added or removed in Task Bar Properties.

Right click on the Task Bar and select Settings.  Look first in Task Bar items.

Then go to Task Bar behaviors.  Then look in Other System Tray Icons.

These are the local settings. See if that helps. As I noted, the Edge icon appears to be fixed in place.

I have one machine with little running on it. If I right click on the Task Bar and unpin Edge, the Edge Icon does not re-appear on start up. The Edge Icon does appear for any app that uses Edge. So ultimately, it might just as well be there.

Other Apps (VMware, Office Outlook, and such) may have settings for task bar apps - so do; some do not.

Otherwise, Windows 11 is not anywhere near as customizable as earlier Windows. I use Power Toys on two machines and that does not seem to affect Edge.

Comment: Thanks for trying but there are no apps listed here that shouldn't be

Comment: You need to use Windows 11 as provided. Edge is fixed, other apps - it varies.  Otherwise, as noted, you must use as it comes.

Comment: I'm sorry and I appreciate the effort, but this is not the case. My colleague has the exact same setup and his apps do not repin to the taskbar every restart

Comment: I am not certain your friend's installation is a valid measurement point. What I posted is how my 3 Windows 11 Pro systems work.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood my problem - the problem is not system tray icons, but the apps being re-pinned to the task bar after every restart and googling will show this is now a common reported bug in windows 11.

Comment: I don't think this is a Windows 11 bug. Make sure you have Windows fully up to date There are Windows 11 icons managed in task bar settings (Widgets and Like). Edge seems to be fixed in place. All other icons are App controlled.

Comment: @Sanchez333  - I did some experiments and amended my answer